# deleting object from ui select options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select

I have an ui-select component and I need to remove the selected object from the option´s list after certain event, So it can´t be selected again. I think it may by achieved with "refresh" property of ui-select-choices.

UI Select:

```
<ui-select data-ng-model="selectedNutriente.selected" theme="bootstrap" name="selectNutriente">
   <ui-select-match placeholder="Elija un Nutriente...">
      <strong>{{$select.selected.abreviatura}} </strong>
      {{$select.selected.nombre}} 
      <small><strong>Tipo de Dato: </strong>               
           {{$select.selected.idTiposDatosAlimentos.nombreTipoDato}}
      </small>
   </ui-select-match>
   <ui-select-choices repeat="a in allNutrientes| filter: $select.search" group-by="groupByNombreTipoDato" refresh=refreshNutrientesList()> 
      <strong>{{a.abreviatura}} </strong>
      {{a.nombre}}
   </ui-select-choices>
```

Basically what I need is to delete item from "allNutrientes" list after some events. So far I haven´t found a way to do this.

Function to call with refresh:

```
$scope.refreshNutrientesList = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tablaCnaGeneralInsertada.length; i++) {
            $scope.allNutrientes.pop($scope.tablaCnaGeneralInsertada[i].nutriente);
            console.log($scope.tablaCnaGeneralInsertada[i].nutriente);
        }
    };
```

The items I need to delete are deleted with this function but in the DOM they are still present. Its like the DOM does not get updated :(

Comment: Could you replicate the issue on a plunker or else? It would be way easier to spot the issue then...

Comment: You´re right. Maybe Im asking way to much from everybody, I will edit my question now, I now is complicated to understand @Fedaykin

Comment: @Fedaykin Ok, please take a look now, I simplified it, In my current situation I can´t make a replicate the issue